# Select list points at region

Tags: regions, coordinate

If I have a list `Table[{dj, di}, {dj, 0, 1, 0.2}, {di, 0, 1, 0.2}]`, how can I select only the points that satisfies $\left(2-\delta_{j}\right)-\sqrt{2\left(2-\delta_{j}\right)\left(1-\delta_{j}\right)}\leq\delta_{i}\leq\delta_{j}$ ?

Comment: You are looking for [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lst = Table[{dj, di}, {dj, 0, 1, 0.2}, {di, 0, 1, 0.2}]

 (* {{{0., 0.}, {0., 0.2}, {0., 0.4}, ..., {1., 0.8}, {1., 1.}}} *)
```

Flatten at level 1 to keep `{dj,di}` points and remove other dimensions

```
lst2 = Flatten[lst, 1]

 (* {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.2}, {0., 0.4}, ..., {1., 0.8}, {1., 1.}} *)
```

Use `Select` to perform a test on each point

````
Select[lst2, 
    #[[2]] >= 2 - #[[1]] - Sqrt[2 (2 - #[[1]]) (1 - #[[1]])] 
    && #[[2]] <= #[[1]] &]
```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Select` to modify the iterator list for `di`:

```
selectIterators[x_] := Select[2 - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(1 - x) (2 - x)] - x <= # <= x &]@*Range
```

***Example:***

```
Join @@ Table[{dj, di}, {dj, 0, 1, .2}, {di, selectIterators[dj][0, 1, .2]}]
```

> ```
> {{0., 0.}, {0.2, 0.2}, {0.4, 0.4}, {0.6, 0.4}, {0.6, 0.6}, 
>  {0.8, 0.6}, {0.8, 0.8}, {1., 1.}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

`Select` is probably the most idiomatic way to do this, but just for fun, here are some other ways to do it by using `Tuples` to generate the list of pairs (avoiding use of the `Flatten`) and defining a function that returns `Nothing` to create an "empty" entry in the list that gets removed (avoiding the use of `Select`).

There's no good reason to do this, other than just to show another way.

```
(*generate list of pairs *) 
lst = Tuples[ {#, #}] &@Range[0, 1, 0.2]


(*define a function that acts on each pair*)
f[{dj_, di_}] := With[
  {val = (2 - dj) - Sqrt[2*(2 - dj)*(1 - dj)]},
  If[val <= di <= dj, {dj, di}, Nothing]]

f /@ lst (*apply the function to the list*)
```

That being said, `Select` is probably more natural here. I'd go with using the operator form by defining the condition to satisfy and then writing a one-liner of the form

```
(*define the condition*)
condition[{di_, dj_}] := With[
  {val = (2 - dj) - Sqrt[2*(2 - dj)*(1 - dj)]},
  val <= di <= dj]

(*compute result as a one-liner*)
Select[condition]@Tuples[{#, #}]&@Range[0, 1, 0.2]
```

In that vein, I suppose if one is allergic to `Tuples` (in addition to `Select` and `Tables`) one could also something like the following:

```
g[dj_, di_] := With[
  {val = (2 - dj) - Sqrt[2*(2 - dj)*(1 - dj)]},
  If[val <= di <= dj, {dj, di}, Nothing]]

Flatten[#, 1]&@ Outer[g, #, #]&@ Range[0, 1, 0.2]
```